# Copying Data in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

We are building a scheduling app in class, and attempting to create a function to allow for the copying of a previous shift, and all employees under that shift to the next week of scheduling.  Here is my code currently:

```
def copy
        set_calendar
        @past_shift = Shift.find(params[:id])
        if @calendar.users.owners.include?(current_user) || @calendar.users.managers.include?(current_user)
          @shift = @past_shift.clone
          if @shift.save
            render json: ("Shift copied successfully"), status: :ok
          else
            render json: @usershift.errors, status: :uprocessable_entity
          end
        else
          render json: ("You do not have access to copy shifts"), status: :unauthorized
        end
end
```

I've used both .clone and .dup, but it seems it only copies the shifts over, without copying the employees associated with those shifts.  Any help or guidance in the right path would be appreciated.

Below is the entire controller for shifts:

```
class ShiftsController < ApplicationController


    def index
        set_calendar

        if params["start_date"] && params["end_date"]
            start_date = params["start_date"].to_date
            end_date = params["end_date"].to_date
            if @calendar.users.include?(current_user)
                @shifts = Shift.where(
                    calendar_id: @calendar.id,
                    start_time: start_date.beginning_of_day .. end_date.end_of_day)
                render "/shifts/index.json", status: :ok
            else
                render json: '{}', status: :unauthorized
            end
        else
            render json: {'error': 'start date and end date are required'}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    def myschedule
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @publishedshifts = @user.shifts.where(published: true)
        if @user
            render "/shifts/index2.json", status: :ok
        else
            render json: ('You do not have access to these shifts'), status: :unauthorized
        end
    end


    def create
        set_calendar
        if @calendar.users.owners.include?(current_user) || @calendar.users.managers.include?(current_user)
          @shift = Shift.new(shift_params)
            if @shift.save
                render "/shifts/create.json", status: :ok
            else
                render json: @shift.errors
            end
        else  render json: ('You do not have access to create a shift.'), status: :unauthorized
        end
    end

    def copy
        set_calendar
        @past_shift = Shift.find(params[:id])
        if @calendar.users.owners.include?(current_user) || @calendar.users.managers.include?(current_user)
          @shift = @past_shift.clone
          if @shift.save
            render json: ("Shift copied successfully"), status: :ok
          else
            render json: @usershift.errors, status: :uprocessable_entity
          end
        else
          render json: ("You do not have access to copy shifts"), status: :unauthorized
        end
    end

    def update
        set_calendar
        set_shift
        if @calendar.users.owners.include?(current_user) || @calendar.users.managers.include?(current_user)
           if @shift.update_attributes(shift_params)
              render "/shifts/update.json", status: :ok
           else
              render json: @shift.errors, status: :uprocessable_entity
           end
        else  render json: ("You don't have access to update shifts."), status: :unauthorized
        end
    end

    def destroy
        set_calendar
        set_shift
        if @calendar.users.owners.include?(current_user) || @calendar.users.managers.include?(current_user)
            if @shift.destroy
                render json: ("Shift deleted!"), status: :ok
            else
                render json: @shift.errors, status: :uprocessable_entity
            end
        else  render json: ("You don't have access to delete shifts.")
        end
    end



    private

    def set_calendar
        @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:calendar_id])
    end

    def set_shift
        @shift = Shift.find(params[:id])
    end


    def shift_params
        params.permit(:start_time, :end_time, :calendar_id, :capacity, :published)
    end
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "api_token"
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  end

  create_table "usershifts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "shift_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["shift_id"], name: "index_usershifts_on_shift_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_usershifts_on_user_id"
  end

create_table "shifts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "start_time"
t.datetime "end_time"
t.bigint "calendar_id"
t.integer "capacity"
t.boolean "published"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["calendar_id"], name: "index_shifts_on_calendar_id"
```

end

Comment: I'm getting the shift to copy over, but the employees of the shifts are not coming through.  Currently I have to put a similar function in the employee shifts controller, and would like a way to do it all in one.

Comment: You need to include the employees in your @past_shift query.  so `@past_shift = Shift.find(params[:id]).includes(:employees)`

Comment: Please provide your data schema -- migrations for ```shifts``` and ```employees``` tables

Comment: ```ActiveRecords```'s ```clone``` methods generates a "shallow" copy of the model. No wonder that associated records not cloned: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/clone

Comment: I'm getting an undefined method 'includes' when attempting this

Comment: I've added the schema

Comment: Yes @IlyaKonyukhov, I've also tried deep_dup as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I suppose you don't want to clone user records when cloning shift. Also, based on the migrations, it seems that `Shift` and `User` models are connected through `usershifts` table, ie `Shift` model `has_many :users, through :usershifts`.

If so, the code can be:

```
@shift = @past_shift.dup
@shift.users = @past_shift.users
if @shift.save
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

`@past_shift.dup` returns a duplicate of the record that hasn't been assigned an id yet and is treated as a new record. `@shift.users = @past_shift.users` copies associated users (it does not create new records in `users` but only in join table `usershifts`, and these records are not saved yet). `@shift.save` saves it all :)

Comment: First, thank you for taking the time to help.  When I attempted this method, I received the following error:  NoMethodError (undefined method `users' for #<Shift::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fbd7048ee20>)

Comment: Well, it means my assumptions were wrong and your Shift model does not have that ```has_many``` association. I think you need to create it.

Comment: The purpose of what we are trying to accomplish is all of the users (aka employees) as well as all of their shifts be copied over week to week.  You are correct, the users and shifts are tied together by usershifts.  My previous attempts at cloning only copied over the shifts, along with using .dup, as well as .deep_dup.  Attempting your method returned error above

Comment: User model has a has_many :shifts, through :usershifts, and usershift model belongs_to both users and shifts.

Comment: Could you try ```dup``` instead of ```clone``` ?

Comment: Yes I attempted that, still gives undefined method users

Comment: ```undefined method `users' for #<Shift::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fbd7048ee20>``` means that ```@shift``` was obtained as ```Shift.where``` call, not ```Shift.find```. Please double check it. If model ```Shift``` has that relation, then non-nil ```Shift.find(...)``` should have ```users```

Comment: It worked, you were correct I had put a .where and forgot to switch it back to .find.  Thanks for the help!